# Is it possible to attach/detach OS disk to/from existing Azure VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Is it possible to attach/detach OS disk to/from existing Azure VM?
Any direct or indirect method?

Answer (score 1):

OS disks are attached to your VM and contains the OS files (boot volume), so I do not think you can directly detach such a disk from a VM and attach to another.

However, you can create a snapshot of an existing OS disk, create another managed disk from it, and create a VM from that disk. This way, you re-create your VM and OS, but it is a new instance of the disk, so expect certain things or permissions not to work as expected.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, it is possible to attach and detach an OS disk to/from an existing Azure virtual machine (VM).

**Azure Portal:**

1. Open the Azure portal and navigate to the virtual machine you want to work with.
2. In the virtual machine's "Overview" blade, click on "Stop" to deallocate the VM

[image]

3. Once the VM is stopped, go to the "Disks" section of the virtual machine.
4. Click on "+ Add data disk" to add a new disk or click on an existing data disk to detach it.

[image]

5. To detach the OS disk, you can't directly do it from the portal.

**Azure PowerShell:**

Attach a new disk:

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "yourResourceGroup" -Name "yourVMName"
$disk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName "yourResourceGroup" -DiskName "yourDiskName"
Add-AzVMDataDisk -VM $vm -Name "NewDiskName" -CreateOption Attach -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -Lun 2
Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "yourResourceGroup" -VM $vm
```

Detach a data disk:

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "yourResourceGroup" -Name "yourVMName"
$vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks.RemoveAt(2)  # Specify the index of the disk you want to detach
Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "yourResourceGroup" -VM $vm
```

**Azure CLI:**

Attach a new disk:

```
az vm disk attach -g yourResourceGroup --vm-name yourVMName --disk yourDiskName --new --lun 2
```

Detach a data disk:

```
az vm disk detach -g yourResourceGroup --vm-name yourVMName --name yourDiskName
```

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.**

Comment: @saisakethguduru , you have shared the command to attach detach data disk how to attach/detach OS disk?